# Altering the opacity of part of a View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I would like to get the following effect. I have an image on my screen. When a navigation drawer (or another obstructing view) comes over the top of my image, I want to instead of having it cover the image, show the negative of the image.

The pictures below may help to show what I mean.

[image: state0][image: state1][image: state2]

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I'd like to get the same effect for the menu icon.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about this is:

1. Enable the drawing cache on the view you want to apply the negative:

   view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
2. Get a snapshot of the view when the drawer is clicked or dragged with :

   Bitmap bmp = view.getDrawingCache();
3. Finally override the onDraw() method of the drawer and draw the bitmap on it. Apply a shader to do the "negative" effect. See: http://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/

Answer (score -1):

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);   
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable);    
Bitmap bm = bd.getBitmap();  

Paint paint = new Paint();    
Where the INT ranges from 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (fully opaque).
paint.setAlpha(0);    

canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, paint);
```

Comment: This effect can't be produced just by using transparency.